# How to compile Selenium on Debian Jessie, failing on ibus

Tags: c++, c, selenium, compilation, compiler-errors

When I compile Selenium on Debian Jessie, it gives me the output below. I have `ibus` lib installed. I think the version I use is different.

How can I solve it?

If you need to provide any environment configuration, write me what cmd output should I post here.

```
...
Compiling: //cpp:imehandler64 as build/cpp/amd64/libimehandler64.so
cpp/imehandler/linux/src/ibushandler.cpp: In member function ‘virtual std::string IBusHandler::GetActiveEngine() const’:
cpp/imehandler/linux/src/ibushandler.cpp:70:37: error: ‘IBusEngineDesc’ has no member named ‘name’
     engine_name = std::string(desc->name);
                                     ^
cpp/imehandler/linux/src/ibushandler.cpp: In member function ‘IBusInputContext* IBusHandler::GetCurrentInputContext() const’:
cpp/imehandler/linux/src/ibushandler.cpp:88:3: error: ‘IBusConnection’ was not declared in this scope
   IBusConnection* conn = ibus_bus_get_connection(bus_);
   ^
cpp/imehandler/linux/src/ibushandler.cpp:88:19: error: ‘conn’ was not declared in this scope
   IBusConnection* conn = ibus_bus_get_connection(bus_);
                   ^
cpp/imehandler/linux/src/ibushandler.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool IBusHandler::IsActivated() const’:
cpp/imehandler/linux/src/ibushandler.cpp:110:47: error: ‘ibus_input_context_is_enabled’ was not declared in this scope
   return ibus_input_context_is_enabled(context);
                                               ^
cpp/imehandler/linux/src/ibushandler.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void IBusHandler::Deactivate()’:
cpp/imehandler/linux/src/ibushandler.cpp:127:37: error: ‘ibus_input_context_disable’ was not declared in this scope
   ibus_input_context_disable(context);
...
```

Comment: Have you tried updating your version of ibus?

Comment: I have fully updated Debian Jessie. How can I (=what cmd should I run) update the ibus?

Comment: As "root", do `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Yes, I know this apt basics, I can confirm with confidence, that I have everthing up to date. Do you have enought reputation to bring this question higher in the listing?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not.

Comment: Maybe someone will find this thread in future and kindly answer it. I also asked at the Selenium forum, but they said basically nothing constructive.